# C++: Why 'delete' memory is way too much slower than 'new' memory

Tags: c++

I am really new to C++. I've found that operator delete is too much slower than operator new.
I have the following code running under MS Visual Studio 2012 with OS being Windows 7 64 bit.

The output is :

---

0
19
....................

Problem has solved. It's because I ran it from IDE. But now I am curious why running it from a debugger would cause such a big difference?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

#define N 10
typedef unsigned long DWORD;
typedef int * PINT;

const DWORD n = 2E6;

time_t time1, time2, time3;

int main()
{   

    PINT *  p = new PINT[n];

    cout << "-----------------" << endl;

    time (&time1);

    for (DWORD i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        p[i] = new int [N];
    }

    time (&time2);

    cout<<time2-time1<<endl;

    for (DWORD i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        delete [] p[i];
    }

    time (&time3);

    cout<<time3-time2<<endl;


    delete [] p;

    cout << "................." << endl;

}
```

Comment: Are you compiling the _release_ or the _debug_ configuration? Remember that profiling the debug configuration is meaningless.

Comment: I don't find any difference, although the resolution of your timer (1 second!) leaves something to be desired.

Comment: You're also using a terrible counter with a sample set that is hideously small.

Comment: Why are you including the timing of previous `cout` call when timing the `delete` statement?

Comment: I don't think your timer is accurate for such short timings.

Comment: It's in Release. I know the counter might not be good, but still it can give some information. I also used GetTickCount() but the conclusion is similar. In this case, cout does not make big difference here.

Comment: I don't see why you think new and delete should take the same time to complete.

Comment: It seems on Linux there's no much difference, but on Windows it does have big difference.

Comment: Do not add `cout` or any I/O to your timing runs.  Doing that invalidates your findings, regardless of how little time it may take.  If you want to write code that does timings, the best advice is to keep each test in its own `{ }` block, and use local timer variables.  That way, there is no chance your timer is timing extraneous stuff (such as I/O from the previous test).

Comment: Are you by chance running it in the debugger?  Outside the debugger both counts are 0.

Comment: It's in Release! Are you using Windows or Linux? @Retired Ninja

Comment: I didn't ask about debug or release, I asked if you were running the executable inside the debugger or not.  When I changed your timing code to time milliseconds and ran the executable outside the debugger I found that new takes 83ms and delete takes 42ms.  This is on Windows using Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Yes! You helped me a lot. I did run it from IDE and when I tried to run it again outside IDE and it was quite fast. As I have said in the post, I am new to programming and it is the first time that it occurred to me running inside and outside debugger can make such a difference.

Answer (score 1):

When you build your program on VS as a debug build, you get a different heap than if you do a release build. The debug heap contains a number of safeguards intended to help you find common programming errors. Such techniques include:

- place guards (sentinels) between allocated blocks, and check they are still intact when the block is freed.
- fill freed blocks with a pattern (that is usually negative and an unaligned pointer), so that programs that use memory after it is freed are likely to trigger problems.
- walk the heap before and/or after block allocation to ensure that all the guards and free patterns are intact.

These special features tend to be invoked on `free` rather than on `new`, so it's unsurprising (to me at least) that `free` is slower.

Don't worry about it. On a release build `free` is plenty fast enough for anything you're like to do.